# AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect options not working

Tags: angularjs, multi-select

I am using AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect - http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/

It looks like it's working, but we have not seen any selected sign. When I select from the dropdown box It's look like-

[image]

Here is my code,

Angular Directive,

```
scope.example9model = []; scope.example9data = [{id: 1, label: "David"}, {id: 2, label: "Jhon"}, {id: 3, label: "Danny"}]; scope.example9settings = {enableSearch: true};
```

Call from HTML,

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example9data" selected-model="example9model" extra-settings="example9settings">
```

what's the problem there I can't figure out this.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Sorry, Now It's added.

Comment: Try printing {{example9model}} above the div tag. Whats the output after multi-selection ?

Comment: okay, Printed result when I select CHeckall option - [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}]

Comment: Whats the problem then. It is working perfectly.

Comment: Need more code. It seems that the values are getting selected correctly but the tick icon is not being displayed. After inspecting the code on the github page i can see that 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok' class is being applied to the span by checking for the idProp value. Posting more code could help to understand the problem better.